# stringByRemovingPercentEncoding resulting in null string

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, nsurl

I've got a file path `/Users/alexandra/Downloads/folder%20with%20spaces/` and I want to remove the percent encoding and make it a file URL. Using the method `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding`  makes the string null.

The documentation says "A new string with the percent-encoded sequences removed, or nil if the receiver contains an invalid percent-encoding sequence.", but I don't see `%20` for a space being wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show us your non-working code in Objective-C, but this works fine on my machine (in Swift):

```
if let path = "/Users/alexandra/Downloads/folder%20with%20spaces/".removingPercentEncoding {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    print(url) // file:///Users/alexandra/Downloads/folder%20with%20spaces/
}
```

On the other hand, since you've already wrongly acquired percent encoding in a string pathname, why not just stick `file://` in front of it and be done with it?

```
let path = "/Users/alexandra/Downloads/folder%20with%20spaces/"
if let url = URL(string: "file://" + path) {
    print(url)
}
```

Comment: This already helped me with my problem. Thanks for making me understand urls better :)